# Pycharm : how-to launch for a standard terminal (to solve an issue with curses)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, curses

I'm facing a weird problem.
Using Pycharm (please do not troll about this fact), I'm trying to launch a short app that uses `ncurses` to render some things on my term.

While I can launch the project in a simple term without any problem, launching it from Pycharm raise the following error :

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
error: setupterm: could not find terminal

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As far as I can see, all is about terminal environment variables. Pycharm launch the project (Run or Debug) from its own instance of the terminal, and curses will not work with it. So, I am wondering how may I configure Pycharm to launch my project inside a regular terminal.

The project is using Python 2.7.
Pycharm is in EAP version 129.258 (doesn't work with other versions, including stables)

Thanks for your attention.

K.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891 or try running PyCharm like this: `open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/`.

Comment: I believe the problem is that PyCharm doesn't use a real terminal, hence you cannot do anything about it. Simply launch the programs from a real terminal.

Comment: @Bakuriu Please, have a look to the entire question before you comment. As you can see, the question mention that the problem IS Pycharm not launching a real term, and the question also hints that I don't wanna just launch it from a regular terminal. Thanks for your attention, anyway :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for the hints ! "open -a" helps, Pycharm works a bit better even though the integrated terminal emulator is very poor at managing curses and has lack of some other capabilities.

Comment: You can have better results with the built-in SSH terminal and localhost connection.

Comment: Yep. That's what I'm trying now. Sadly (and @Bakuriu was right on this point), it seems we cannot do anything else to ask Pycharm to launch a better console. Thanks, again.

Comment: I don't use pycharm but it may work by running your app in a regular terminal through the remote debugger for debugging.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the curses debugging problem by attaching the debugger to a process.

- Start the program in a terminal
- Pycharm -> Tools -> Attach to Process
- Select my prog
- Done

Trying to attach as non-root requires additional ptrace access rights.

Explained here: http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535

On my ubuntu machine: 
`echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` (as root)

respectively set `ptrace_scope to 0 in /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`

Comment: Note it is "PyCharm -> Run -> Attach To Process" now.

Answer (score -1):

- Start PyCharm and make sure that ncurses is listed in File->Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreter;
- if you have 2.7 and 3.x interpreters installed, make sure that correct one(supporting ncurses) is selected as default for the project from which you launch your application;

I more than sure that you have both 2.7 and 3.x installed on your machine - I had most of the issues with pycharm for case where both Python's branch were installed.