# Send password to sftp subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, sftp, openssh

```
import subprocess

password= "xyz"

p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S", "whoami"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print (p.communicate((password+"\n").encode())) 


ps = subprocess.Popen(["sftp", "user@sftphost"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print (ps.communicate((password+"\n").encode())) # without print as well I get prompted for password
```

First command (`sudo -S whoami`) is successful through `subprocess` taking the password correctly. However, the password is not accepted for `sftp` command – I am still getting prompted to enter password.

I have the same question as [Use subprocess to send a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password). However, I do not want to use the solution like Pexpect or `expect`. I have tried rest of the solutions.

Want to know why this fails for `sftp` and is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH `sftp` always reads the password from the terminal (it does not have an equivalent of `sudo` `-S` switch).

There does not seem to be a readily available way to emulate a terminal with `subprocess.Popen`, see: 
[How to call an ncurses based application using subprocess module in PyCharm IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20316100/850848)

---

You can use all the hacks that are commonly used to automate password authentication with OpenSSH `sftp`, like `sshpass` or Expect:
[How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)

Or use a public key authentication.

---

Though even better is to use a native Python SFTP module like [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) or [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/).

With them, you won't have these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

sftp does not read the password from stdin, but it opens /dev/tty instead. That's the reason why sending the passwod via communicate won't work.

Instead you can use pubkey authentication and use a batchfile (sftp -b) for your sftp commands. As an alternative you can also interact with sftp using pexpect (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).