# How can I use the Tensorflow debugger in PyCharm on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, pycharm

I am trying to use the Tensonflow debugger in PyCharm. When I do I get this error: `_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal`

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mddrill/PycharmProjects/NumberReaderNN/number_reader.py", line 163, in <module>
    [optimizer, loss_func, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py", line 411, in run
    self._run_call_count))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 210, in on_run_start
    self._prep_cli_for_run_start()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 228, in _prep_cli_for_run_start
    self._run_cli = ui_factory.get_ui(self._ui_type)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/ui_factory.py", line 56, in get_ui
    return curses_ui.CursesUI(on_ui_exit=on_ui_exit)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 263, in __init__
    self._screen_init()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 374, in _screen_init
    self._stdscr = curses.initscr()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

The debugger works if I run the code from a terminal, so this is definitely a PyCharm issue.

I have tried what I saw in another answer which is to add `TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo` to the environment variables in Run>Edit Configurations>Defaults>Python and that didn't work. The answer pertained to linux, and I'm on Mac OS X.

How can I get the Tensonflow debugger to work in PyCharm on Mac OS X?

Comment: Have you tried attaching to the process: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31400673/3657941

Comment: @DavidCullen It seems to be hanging on "Attaching to a process with PID=<number>". Either way it would defeat the purpose of using the IDE if I had to start a terminal to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: You are right, it seems this is an open issue in PyCharm:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13062

---

**OLD:** Tipically, you need to set the proper environment variables:

```
export TERM=xterm-new
export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
```

An almost identical problem has been discussed here: [Setupterm could not find terminal, in Python program using curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485699/setupterm-could-not-find-terminal-in-python-program-using-curses)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on Mac. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the 'Edit Configuration' page, and select 'Emulate in output console'.